# 500 server error?

Tags: java, php, google-app-engine, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I got quercus up and running on GAE and when I process this code I get Error: Server Error

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets');
$user="user";
$pass="pass";
try {
      $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass,
                Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME);
    } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_AuthException $ae) {
      exit("Error: ". $ae->getMessage() ."\nCredentials provided were email: [$user] and password [$pass].\n");
    }
?>
```

---

The thing is GAE is blocking every curl request and I can't make the request to the Spreadsheets

Comment: Maybe you should tell us more about your code ?

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine, i don't get Server Error. Just the credential exception. Are you sure you have curl installed?

Comment: Forget it i thought you needed curl but it uses stream_socket_client so you have it installed with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use curl on App Engine. You need to use [URLFetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/).